# Why is Ruby on Rails called a domain-specific language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dsl

Recently, when I tried to explain why Ruby on Rails is a domain-specific language (DSL) to an intern at my organisation, I was not able to articulate my reasoning to the effect I would like to. Maybe I do not understand the space well enough to teach the nuances. Redirecting him to Martin Fowler' [article](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainSpecificLanguage.html) or the Google ranked one InfoQ or other material has not helped much either.

Can some explain why Rails is a DSL with an example / parallel situation which is not voodoo stuff for someone who is fairly new to the world of code? Understanding the ideology might also help in elaborating the intricacies of the rails ecosystem?

Comment: By voodoo stuff i probably would mean something like this http://jroller.com/rolsen/entry/building_a_dsl_in_ruby1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Technically, ruby is not a DSL, it just lends itself to writing internal DSLs very cleanly. [This link](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InternalDslStyle.html) to Martin's Fowler's blog wiki should help clarify things.

Rails has been described as a DSL although I think of it more precisely as a framework that makes very good use of a few DSLs.

Edit:  The [intro to the public version of Martin Fowler's DSL book](http://martinfowler.com/dslwip/Intro.html) has a motivating example, although it is still aimed a bit more at programmers.

Edit again: The "voodoo" example can be useful if you point out that ruby allows ruby code to look like

```
port 2001

respond :resource=>"/hello" do  |request, response|
  response.body = "<message>hello</message>"
end
```

which is cleaner than calling the methods directly.  Implementing a DSL can require "voodoo" like code (it is *much* harder creating a DSL than using one), and in general someone relatively new to coding should worry first about what the DSL does and not so much how it is implemented.

What makes ruby good at internal DSLs includes (1) use of blocks (any language with clean closures has this advantage), (2) method class that do not require parentheses, and (3) the ability to modify classes on the fly (which is what `validates` does).  There are probably more I haven't thought of.

Comment: I think the key is that Rails is a framework that combines several DSLs for describing properties of your webapp.

Answer (score 5):

Ruby is a language that you can use to create a DSL. Ruby on Rails may be considered a DSL (Domain Specific Language) for creating web applications.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby is certainly not a DSL. It's a general purpose language, which is the opposite of a DSL. It is, however, a language that is very suitable as a host for internal-style DSLs. That is; You can use Ruby to create DSLs with.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked myself the same question when working  with the [Capybara testing "DSL"](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master#the-dsl). 
To my mind, when referring to Ruby frameworks like Rails as DSLs the term is simply misued. So, the answer to your question would be: it's called a DSL because of Ruby programmer jargon.

To be fair, following Martin Fowler's suggestion (see [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainSpecificLanguage.html)), we could call those frameworks **internal DLSs** (a subset of a general purpose language for a specific purpose). But I don't think there is a lot of conceptual difference to the notion of a **framework**.

Ruby's kind of unique syntactical flexibility just seems to make frameworks written in a certain style look like a whole new language (albeit a very simple one). Personally I wouldn't call anything a domain specific language which does not have unique syntax or is just a subset of a general purpose language (you can see some support for this in [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725562/domain-specific-language-dsl-vs-frameworks)).

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand the question. Ruby is not a Domain Specific Language, it is a General Purpose Language. It doesn't make sense to call it a DSL, because it isn't one. Therefore the whole premise of the question doesn't make sense.