# Domain Specific Language (DSL) vs. Frameworks

Tags: frameworks, dsl

What is the main difference between the main idea of DSL and Frameworks? These two issues are very confusing to me and i couldn't find a proper answer through internet!

Comment: I haven't read this in detail myself, but it looks like this is one of the more authoritative discussions on this topic: http://folk.uio.no/martifag/masterthesis/thesis.pdf . I'd love to have a concise summary myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. This is the simplest explanation I see:

> A DSL can have its own concrete syntax. A framework cannot have its own syntax since
> it is used in the same language in which it was created. [Domain Speciﬁc Languages versus Frameworks](https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/10059/Johansen.pdf#page=65)

For example: HTML is a DSL, whereas directives in the AngularJS framework are written in HTML syntax so do not constitute a separate language.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Finally i found my answer in that paper 2-3 days ago. However for asking this question, i got a lot of negative points while it was a true and important question!

Comment: I don't know what such people's problem is. I even asked Martin Fowler about this on Twitter. Apparently chapter 2 of his book comments on this.

Comment: I asked someone else who I consider very smart who said "a DSL is one particular implementation of a framework." While that might be true, I don't think that's the most helpful way of looking at it.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat The link seems to be broken.

Comment: I don't know where the official document resides, but I think this is a mirror: https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/10059/Johansen.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y